# React mapping ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, undefined

Im trying to map the list of my **expense** array elements and after using the `map()` method Im getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined **(reading 'toLocaleString')**".
I couldn't find the issue please check the code link - https://github.com/mohitdevelops/react-lessons/tree/main/toLocalString-issue

Please help me out, I'm stuck in this error for days.

And checkout the screenshot here

[image]

Comment: Please check whether the variable at line 5 on ExpenseDate.js is undefined. As a temporary work-around, please change: `const month = props.expenseDate.toLocaleString()` to `const month = props?.expenseDate?.toLocaleString() ?? '';`. Please share your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong object keys in your `expenseData` object in the `ExpenseForm` component. And so the `date` will "always" be `undefined` thus failed during the date conversion in your `ExpenseDate` component. To fix this, you just need to supply the correct object:

From this:

```
const expenseData = {
    inputValue: enteredValue,
    inputAmount: enteredAmount,
    inputDate: new Date(enteredDate),
};
```

To this:

```
const expenseData = {
    id: "e5", // You will need to figure out a way to create a dynamic ID here :)
    title: enteredValue,
    amount: enteredAmount,
    date: new Date(enteredDate),
};
```