# How to format the value in price to numbers with decimals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux, react-redux

this is the code

```
<div className="flex-box d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <h6>Price</h6>
    <span>
        $ {product.price.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2,})}
    </span>
</div>
```

it shows no error

[image]

but when I look at it, it shows this

[image]

how do I solve this? I just want to price to be like $ 1,399.99

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React mapping ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71476298/react-mapping-error-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-tolocalestrin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Intl.NumberFormat for number formating

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, on the run time, you don't have the `product.price` so it results in "undefined".
you have to check for its availability before using any other methods chained to it.
you can simply do this:

```
product?.price?.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2,})
```

By adding ? you are using optional chaining. and you won't see the error.